# Why are two strings evaluated as one concetinated string

Tags: c++, c, string, char

Is is `"Hallo" " Welt"` equivalent to `"Hallo Welt"`?

Should is the following code throw any error or warning at compile time?

```
#include <iostream>

void print(std::string s) { 
    std::cout << s; 
}

int main() {
    print("Hallo" " Welt");
}
```

Using `icc 15.0.3` and -Wall no error or warning is thrown and it prints out `Hallo Welt`.

The background of my question is that clang-format has broken a long string into two, like in the example above.

What happens in `C` using `char*`?

Comment: If you want a formal answer you need to pick *one* language.

Comment: Perfectly legal.  A C99 extension, if I recall.  The compiler concatenates adjacent strings at compile time.

Comment: @SteveSummit It's been the same at least since C89.

Comment: "*What happens in `C` using `char*`?*" why not just try it?

Comment: @alk Please remember that "just try it" is dubious advice -- for example, it's the last thing you want someone do do when they're wondering what the "correct" behavior of `i++ + i++` is.

Comment: @SteveSummit: agreed. But here the context obviously is different.And even more would lead to defined bahaviour.